# コンパイルエラー　[expected initializer before ‘Render’] の意味が知りたい

Tags: c++

#### 質問内容

以下のソースファイルでエラーが発生するのですがこのエラーコードの意味がわかりません。
`expected initializer before ‘Render’`日本語訳 `「Render」の前に必要な初期化子`とは何をすればいいのでしょうか？

#### 知りたいこと

Renderの前に必要な初期化子とは何か知りたい

#### 参考サイト

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968329/c-error-expected-initializer-before-variablename
https://qiita.com/hmito/items/9d928322ca978319da59

#### エラーコード

```
src/Render.hpp: At global scope:
src/Render.hpp:73:36: error: expected initializer before ‘Render’
   73 | T Render<T>::SpriteVertexAttribute Render<T>::spriteVertex[4] = Rendr::SpriteVertexAttribute{ {0,0,0},{0,0}};    //スプライト頂点属性
      |                                    ^~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:25: obj/Render.o] エラー 1


    FrameWork Compile Error
```

#### エラーコード 　(一番左側のTを消した時のエラー)

```
rc/Render.hpp: At global scope:
src/Render.hpp:72:1: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘FrameWork::Render<T>::SpriteVertexAttribute’ because ‘FrameWork::Render<T>’ is a dependent scope
   72 | Render<T>::SpriteVertexAttribute Render<T>::spriteVertex[4] = Render::SpriteVertexAttribute{ {0,0,0},{0,0}};    //スプライト頂点属性
      | ^~~~~~~~~
      | typename 
make: *** [Makefile:23: obj/Render.o] エラー 1
```

#### ヘッダー部

```cpp
#ifndef ___RENDER_HPP___
#define ___RENDER_HPP___

#include "Component.hpp"

#include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"
#include "glm/glm.hpp"


#include <glew/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

#include <memory>

namespace FrameWork
{
    class GameObject;
    class Material;

    template<typename T>
    class Render : public Component<T>
    {
    public:

        static void Init();

        Render()
        {
        
            glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
            
            glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

            glBindVertexArray(vao);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(SpriteVertexAttribute), spriteVertex, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

            glBindVertexArray(0);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        
        }

        ~Render();

        static void SetSpriteAttribute(glm::ivec2 s);


        virtual void RenderBuffer(const glm::mat4 view) = 0;

        std::shared_ptr<Material> material;        


        struct SpriteVertexAttribute
        {
            float position[3];
            float uv[2];
        };

        static SpriteVertexAttribute spriteVertex[4];

    protected:
    
        GLuint vao;
        GLuint vbo;

        
    private:    
    };


template<typename T>
T Render<T>::SpriteVertexAttribute Render<T>::spriteVertex[4];

//template<typename T>
//Render<T>::SpriteVertexAttribute Render<T>::spriteVertex[4];
}
#endif
```

#### ソース部

```cpp
#include "Render.hpp"
#include "Material.hpp"
#include "Window.hpp"
#include <iostream>

/*####################################
# 初期化
######################################*/
template<typename T>
void FrameWork::Render<T>::Init()
{
    //UV座標
    spriteVertex[0].uv[0] = 0;
    spriteVertex[0].uv[1] = 0;

    spriteVertex[1].uv[0] = 0;
    spriteVertex[1].uv[1] = 1;

    spriteVertex[2].uv[0] = 1;
    spriteVertex[2].uv[1] = 0;

    spriteVertex[3].uv[0] = 1;
    spriteVertex[3].uv[1] = 1;


    // 頂点座標
    spriteVertex[0].position[0] = -0.5f;
    spriteVertex[0].position[1] = 0.5f;
    spriteVertex[0].position[2] = 0;

    spriteVertex[1].position[0] = -0.5f;
    spriteVertex[1].position[1] = -0.5f;
    spriteVertex[1].position[2] = 0;

    spriteVertex[2].position[0] = 0.5f;
    spriteVertex[2].position[1] = 0.5f;
    spriteVertex[2].position[2] = 0;

    spriteVertex[3].position[0] = 0.5f;
    spriteVertex[3].position[1] = -0.5f;
    spriteVertex[3].position[2] = 0;

}


/*####################################
# スプライトの頂点属性をリセット 
######################################*/
template<typename T>
void FrameWork::Render<T>::SetSpriteAttribute(glm::ivec2 s)
{
    if( (s.x <= 0) || (s.y <= 0) )
    {
        std::cout<<"Material Error: サイズが不正です。"<< std::endl;        
    }

    //UV座標
    spriteVertex[0].uv[0] = 0;
    spriteVertex[0].uv[1] = 0;

    spriteVertex[1].uv[0] = 0;
    spriteVertex[1].uv[1] = 1;

    spriteVertex[2].uv[0] = 1;
    spriteVertex[2].uv[1] = 0;

    spriteVertex[3].uv[0] = 1;
    spriteVertex[3].uv[1] = 1;


    glm::vec2 size;
    size.x = (1.0f / Window::context->getSize().x) * s.x;
    size.y = (1.0f / Window::context->getSize().y) * s.y;

    // 頂点座標
    spriteVertex[0].position[0] = -size.x;
    spriteVertex[0].position[1] = size.y;
    spriteVertex[0].position[2] = 0;

    spriteVertex[1].position[0] = -size.x;
    spriteVertex[1].position[1] = -size.y;
    spriteVertex[1].position[2] = 0;

    spriteVertex[2].position[0] = size.x;
    spriteVertex[2].position[1] = size.y;
    spriteVertex[2].position[2] = 0;

    spriteVertex[3].position[0] = size.x;
    spriteVertex[3].position[1] = -size.y;
    spriteVertex[3].position[2] = 0;

}




/*####################################
# デストラクタ
######################################*/
template<typename T>
FrameWork::Render<T>::~Render()
{

}
```

Comment: 行頭の`T`が余計でしょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

やりたいことはクラス変数の初期化でしょうから、行頭の`T`は誤記（不要）ですね。

```
template<typename T>
T Render<T>::SpriteVertexAttribute Render<T>::spriteVertex[4] = Render::SpriteVertexAttribute{ {0,0,0},{0,0}};    //スプライト頂点属性
```

コンパイラーは、以下のように変数名の後ろは初期化子を期待しているのに、その位置に初期化子ではない`Render<T>::spriteVertex[4]`が書かれているので、"expected initializer before ‘Render’"だと言っているのでしょう。

```
型 変数名 = 初期化子;
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問ですが回答どおり修正してもエラーが出ますこれはなぜでしょうか？`need ‘typename’ before ‘FrameWork::Render<T>::SpriteVertexAttribute’ because ‘FrameWork::Render<T>’ is a dependent scope
`

Comment: `T`がテンプレートパラメーターであるため、`Render<T>::SpriteVertexAttribute`が型なのか定数なのかコンパイラーには不明です。なので型であるなら、前に`typename`を付けて型であることを明示する必要があります。

Comment: 以下のようにすることで解決しました`template<typename T>
typename Render<T>::SpriteVertexAttribute Render<T>::spriteVertex[4];
`